# 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable for this small code

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
import numpy as np


def main():
    try:
        date, price, open = np.loadtxt('CARG.csv', delimiter=',',
                                       unpack=True, dtype='str')

        x = 0
        for eachDate in date:
            saveLine = eachDate + ',' + price[x] + '\n'
            saveFile = open('newCSV', 'a')
            saveFile.write(saveLine)
            saveFile.close()
            x += 1

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


main()
```

Comment: `open` seems to be a reserved word in python, You should refrain from using it as variable name.

Comment: Don't just describe the exception, copy the whole thing and paste it here. Python shows you where the exception happens, so you don't have to guess. But if you don't let us see that, we do have to guess.

Comment: @ZdaR If `open` were a builtin, this wouldn't happen—it would be a SyntaxError. The problem is that `open` is a perfectly normal identifier, so it _is_ legal to assign to it.

Comment: As a side note, you usually don't want to open and close a file each time through a loop. Instead, open it before the loop and close it at the end. (If you were doing this temporarily so you can, e.g., `less -f` the file to see your script working for debugging purposes, you can `saveFile.flush()` instead.) Also, you probably want to use a `with` statement, so the file gets closed even if there's an exception. Meanwhile, is there a reason you're creating the CSV manually with string concatenation instead of using numpy to do it?

Comment: One more thing: You can use `for x, eachDate in enumerate(date):` instead of manually managing that `x` counter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the side notes. I changed my code according to your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've named a local variable `open`, which shadows the builtin function of the same name—but then tried to use the builtin a couple lines later:

```
date, price, open = …

saveFile = open('newCSV', 'a')
```

So, instead of calling the builtin, you're calling the array. Which obviously doesn't work.

The solution is just to give your variable a different name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it helped me:

```
import io

with io.open('filename') as f:
  #"Doing something you want to do with file"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).